# In app store or paypal or something else?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I am building an app which provides translational service. User can request service in the application after selecting various option like language, phone number, etc. Information will be sent to our server and a call from our customer support specialist will be made to customer to provide translational service (language interpreter). Customer will be charged per minute basis for the incoming call.
Can I use in app purchase feature to charge payment? OR should I use paypal sdk integration for the same or any other option if you can suggest? I have checked out in app purchase guidelines but I am not clear on this.
https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

I know Apple rejects apps which are not per to their guidelines. I emailed to app review team as well but their answer was vague and just pointing to guidelines.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use in-app purchase to charge payment, as long as your terms of use of the app can confidently categorize the transaction item as being digital content.

Perhaps you could sell a call pass, or something.  But the general pattern is to make delivery after the transaction is complete, not deliver a service (by way of digital content voucher) and then charge after.  A purchase could be for pass for a certain amount of minutes, that would need to be complete prior to the call being connected.  That's just a thought.

Let me guide you to a relevant part of the IAP Guidelines that you linked to.  Please review the **In-App Purchase Categories** section. You will find some examples, make note of the VoIP and poker chip examples:

> Digital content is typically Non-Consumable unless the content is
>   expected to be used only  once in which case it would be Consumable.
>   Here are some examples of digital content and  what purchase type
>   would be applicable:
>
> **Example Content | Allowed | Purchase Type**
>
> Buy a digital book | ✔ | Non-Consumable
>
> Buy virtual poker chips for use within a single app | ✔ | Consumable
>
> VoIP minutes, U.S.A to Germany | ✔ | Consumable
>
> Buy an item for in-game use | ✔ | Consumable if single use, otherwise Non-Consumable
>
> Here are additional examples of content that would not be allowed with
>   details about why they are not allowable:
>
> **Example Content | Allowed | Why Is This Not Allowed?**
>
> Buy a physical book | X | Physical items cannot be purchased
>
> Buy virtual poker chips for use in multiple apps | X | Items can only be used in the app where the  purchase is made